# Decryption failed because the HMAC could not be validated

Tags: 7

I am using the [Encrypt](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) module to encrypt some of user object data.

I can encrypt data, but while decrypt it, I get the following error:

> Decryption failed because the HMAC could not be validated

```php
encrypt('name') // It works.
decrypt('some encrypted data') // It throws the above error.
```

How can I decrypt data using that module?

Answer (score 0):

***I have found below solution.*** I have un-serialized encrypted data. Found below details.

[image]

Used above input to decrypt function.

```
$options = array();
$method = 'mcrypt_aes_cbc';
$key_provider = 'drupal_variable';
$config = array('provider_settings' => array('method' => 'variable_contents')); // I have updated method name later.
decrypt('encrypted_text', $options, $method, $key_provider, $config); // It works now :)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me turns out that the value of the body that was being retrieved had `<p>` tags around it.

Ex:

> `<p>`a:6:{s:4:"text";s:128:"Kuh1EzLdKbebW7WI7mPLKo/g2HEA4R3c+Y3b+IKF0MGH3Oa8Bc7x5Gh+u+9wmc8EKGyc4Gdudwtvb3n6EjXNL6cIrr6EZDSsHFafspObcxYpNJhQBKGAf6134PiC4jqv";s:6:"method";s:14:"mcrypt_aes_cbc";s:12:"key_provider";s:4:"file";s:7:"options";a:0:{}s:15:"method_settings";s:0:"";s:17:"provider_settings";a:2:{s:4:"path";s:19:"sites/default/files";s:6:"method";s:13:"base64_decode";}}`</p>`

so all I had to do was strip those tags.

```
  $body = $vars['message_body'];
  $body = strip_tags($body);
  $vars['message_body'] = decrypt($body);
```